# How do I change an image source with CSS?

Tags: css

I would like to change the displayed image just with CSS

```
<a href="/"><img id="image1" src="http://somepic.jpg"></a>
```

since there is no css for `src` I think, I must make it transparent and display another image in the background somehow?

Comment: you cant change the src attribute of an image-tag with css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. You could change it with Javascript.

With CSS, you could set the image to `display:none;` set a `background-image` on a parent element.

Comment: +1 for a solid work-around, but like you said, Javascript is the way to go.

Comment: You can also set the image to `visibility: hidden` instead of `display: none` so that the parent will keep the same size as the image, but show the `background-image` in its place.

Comment: I set the surrounding a-tag to `display:block; width:100px;height:50px;background:url('/some_otherpic.jpg');background-repeat:no-repeat;`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following alternatives:

- (especially) If the `<img>`s lend no semantic value, remove them entirely in favor of putting `background-image`s on other elements.
- If the new images lend semantic value to the document, and you're ok with them being pre-loaded, insert them as additional `<img>`s and just hide one or the other with css (assuming this is for a `hover` or other similarly conditional effect)
- Change the `src` with javaScript

Answer (score 0):

Although its true that CSS is made for presentation only but CAS (Cascading Attribute Sheet) is been proposed and under thought, also I think for basic purpose below code should work for you ,

```
<style>
a:after
{
content:url(your_image.jpg);
}
#image1
{
display:none;
}
</style>
```